# VLC won't become default for MP3 or MP4

Tags: itunes, quicktime, vlc

I have tried a number of times to make VLC Media player the default for MP3 and MP4. I open a file and tick the "Always open with" checkbox, but they still open with iTunes and QuickTime by default respectively. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try one of these 2 solutions I hope they'll solve your problem:

1-  use "[Default Apps](http://creativetechs.com/tipsblog/set-default-applications-in-mac-os-x/)" for change every default application.

[image]

2- From the Finder, select a MP-4 file, open the Info panel (`File` ➔ `Get Info` or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>), select your preferred application and then click `Change All…`

[image]

Comment: So "Always open with" only applies to one file?

Comment: @Casebash, Yes if you "Always open with" it just work for the specific file(s).

Answer (score 2):

You can use utility like [Magic Launch](http://michelf.com/software/magic-launch/) to do that.